# create two dataframes based on regex

Tags: python, pandas

Here is a small sample of dataframe I would like to split into two separate dataframes.

```
  No    Code         Name Rem Last Done   LACP     Chg  % Chg Vol ('00)  \
0  1    0012       3A [S]   s     0.940  0.940       -      -        20   
1  2    7054    AASIA [S]   s         -  0.205       -      -         -   
2  3    5238      AAX [S]   s     0.345  0.340   0.005  +1.47    37,806   
3  4  5238WA   AAX-WA [S]   s     0.135  0.135       -      -       590   
4  5    7086  ABLEGRP [S]   s     0.095  0.100  -0.005  -5.00       300
```

I want to filter on the "Code" column based on matching or not matching the following python regular expression:

```
"^[0-9]{1,5}$"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing), `~` is for inverting boolean mask:

```
m = df['Code'].str.contains("^[0-9]{1,5}$")

df1 = df[m]
print (df1)
   No  Code     Name  Rem Last   Done   LACP     Chg  % Chg Vol ('00)
0   1  0012       3A  [S]    s  0.940  0.940       -      -        20
1   2  7054    AASIA  [S]    s      -  0.205       -      -         -
2   3  5238      AAX  [S]    s  0.345  0.340   0.005  +1.47    37,806
4   5  7086  ABLEGRP  [S]    s  0.095  0.100  -0.005  -5.00       300

df2 = df[~m]
print (df2)
   No    Code    Name  Rem Last   Done   LACP Chg % Chg Vol ('00)
3   4  5238WA  AAX-WA  [S]    s  0.135  0.135   -     -       590
```

**Detail**:

```
print (m)
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: Code, dtype: bool

print (~m)
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4    False
Name: Code, dtype: bool
```

Comment: I was having trouble wrapping my head around how boolean indexing would work for this application.  Thank you for the illustration.

Comment: is it possible to an "or" condition?  something like  m = df['Code'].str.contains("^[0-9]{1,5}$" | "5235SS" )

Comment: @TimothyLombard - You can use `m = df['Code'].str.contains("^[0-9]{1,5}$|5235SS") `